# Search and Adding Item in Dynamic ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to dynamically add name of movies  in listview and after that i want to use search option to find the movie name if movie name is not found in a listview add the movie in listview.My problem is Before using search, movie name inserted in a listview properly After using search, movie name not inserted in listview.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

        ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        EditText et,inputSearch;


        Button btn;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            final EditText inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
            btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);


            inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                    MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);  
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
                }
            });
            }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (isInputValid(et)) {
                listItems.add(0,et.getText().toString());
                et.setText("");

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }




    }

             protected boolean isInputValid(EditText etInput2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generatd method stub
                    if (etInput2.getText().toString().trim().length()<1) {
                        etInput2.setError("Please Enter Item");
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }



    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

put log in protected boolean isInputValid(EditText etInput2) { method to see if it returns false or true.
and also check it this method is getting the string properly..

if it returns what you want and you get the correct string inside the method, put log in the public void onClick(View v) { method to see if you get the string from the isInputValid method, and so you will know if the problem is in listItems.add(0,et.getText().toString()); or before/after..

Comment: I have added toast in Onclick(View v)  it return the value but list is not updated.

Comment: how to refresh the list

Comment: When you try the add() method some where else in the code, eg OnCreate() does it work? does the list get the item properly?   BTW, Where is your ListView variable? all I can see is the ArrayList<String>, but thats not what you see in the application itself, you see a ListView, which is a View.. you need to populate the ListView with the ArrayList!

Comment: Thanks every one for helping I find my mistake and now it' s done.